# what do we call a person who works in reinforcing steel?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the right term to describe a person who works in cutting reinforcing steel (rebar). This person would cut the steel bars and shape them to fit the project he/she working on.
Is there a term for the person whose job is to cut and prepare rebars to be used in buildings? 
A photo is attached. [image]

Comment: Hmm. You can look up *ironworker* and *steel mill worker*, then come back if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: I would probably go for the generic "Construction worker."

Comment: @vickyace The rebar probably isn't cut to length at the steel mill (they would just sell standard lengths) so the worker probably isn't a steel mill worker.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I worked in a rod mill at one time where we rolled reinforcing rod among other products. Whatever anyone else did with it afterwards it left us in the form of 2 tonne coils!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia gives the following terms:

- [reinforcing ironworker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironworker#Reinforcing_ironworker) (US);
- [steel fixer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_fixer) (UK);
- rod buster (colloquial, US).